# Open toggle by default

Tags: css, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery

So I've this accordions on my page [jsfiddle.net/p4vQK/](http://jsfiddle.net/p4vQK/) and would like to have the exact same set of accordions on the same page but with the first toggle opened by default.

This is the js code I use to make the first toggle active

```
$('.accordion .accordion-content:eq(0)').slideDown();
$('.accordion .accordion-title:eq(0)').attr('stus', 'active').addClass('active');
```

However it doesn't work when 2 sets of accordions are on the same page.

Hope someone help me achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: The js code you mention in your post seems to work fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @user1506980 this code doesnt work when there is 2 accordions in the page (only 1 open when there should be 2).

Comment: Is that the desired result? For both sets of accordions to have the first child open by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting with `eq()`, try selecting with first-child :

```
$('.accordion li:first-child .accordion-content').slideDown();
$('.accordion li:first-child .accordion-title').attr('stus', 'active').addClass('active');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p4vQK/3/

I also change something since your code wasnt working when there is multiple accordions.

You need to close accordions in the same ul :

```
$(this).closest('.accordion').find('.accordion-content').slideUp();
$(this).closest('.accordion').find('.accordion-title').attr('stus', '').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: Great I've just tested your code and worked fine but how do I have one of the accordions set to have all toggles closed by default? So basically I want one set with all toggles closed and another one with the first toggle open by default.
Thank you so much ;)

Comment: @user1628193 the easiest way would be to add an id to your accordions, and perform the slideDown on the first accordion. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydHkd/) , or you could use `$('.accordion:eq(0) li:first-child .accordion-content').slideDown();`